# Is Google Documentation outdated?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

Something that confuses me is this found on the Google Developer Console documentation regarding [Setting up OAuth2.0](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#generatingoauth2)

> Setting up OAuth 2.0
>
> To use OAuth 2.0 in your application, you need an OAuth 2.0 client ID,
>   which your application uses when requesting an OAuth 2.0 access token.
>   When you register an application in the Google Developers Console, you
>   can generate an OAuth 2.0 client ID.
>
> To find your application's client ID and client secret, and set a
>   redirect URI, expand the OAuth 2.0 Client ID section.
>
> To deactivate the client ID, delete the application from the
>   Developers Console.

How do you "**expand the OAuth 2.0 Client ID section**" ? Here is a screenshot of this screen:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Screen shot from "original" developer console interface:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The terminology used is for the original Developer Console, whereas you have been redirected to the new Cloud Console. Personally I find the original more robust so I tend to use that. Look at the bottom of teh page and you'll see a grey link "Return to Original"

Comment: I still don't know how to "expand the OAuth 2.0 Client ID section. See the update with a screen shot of the "original" developer console interface.

Comment: @marienke , even i am facing same problem, do you got the solution yet ? Pinoyyid, as shown in updated ques "original" developer console interface doesnt show OAuth 2.0 Client ID section

Comment: click "Create Client New Client Id"

Comment: I ended up working through the Android Google Play Services Samples - under auth